# Custom module does not display in page

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks, template

I'm trying to add custom block module to homepage but it does not load my `block.phtml` file. Here are my files:
**app/etc/modules/MG_Block.xml:**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MG_MyBlock>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MG_MyBlock>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/MG/MyBlock/etc/config.xml:**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MG_MyBlock>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MG_MyBlock>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mg_myblock>
                <class>MG_MyBlock_Block</class>
            </mg_myblock>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>`
```

**app/code/local/MG/MyBlock/Block/Products.php:**

```
class MG_MyBlock_Block_Products extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract{
    public function index(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/mg/products.phtml:**

```
<?php echo $this->index(); ?>
```

**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/local.xml:**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content"> 
            <block type="mg_myblock/products" output="toHtml" name="myblock" template="mg/products.phtml" after="-" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

When I use `var_dump` in `_construct()` function in my block it shows `var_dump` but it does not load template file.

Comment: add your controller code for more idea.

Comment: I extend `Mage_Core_Block_Template` instead of `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

First add "module.xml" in layout tag in "config.xml".

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MG_MyBlock>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MG_MyBlock>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mg_myblock>
                <class>MG_MyBlock_Block</class>
            </mg_myblock>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <myblock>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>myblock</module>
                    <frontName>formtest</frontName>
                </args>
            </myblock>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then define "module.xml".

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <formtest_myblock_index>
        <reference name="content"> 
            <block type="mg_myblock/products" output="toHtml" name="myblock" template="mg/products.phtml" after="-" />
        </reference>
    </formtest_myblock_index>
</layout>
```

Try with this.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file MG_Block.xml in app/etc/modules/ to MG_MyBlock.xml